# How can I insert or get content control, Outlook Web Add-in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

In the Word Web Add-in I can insert a content control by `context.document.getSelection().insertContentControl()` and get all of them by `context.document.contentControls` how can I do that in Outlook Web Add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Controls are exclusive to Word. Outlook uses either `HTML` or plain text.

Comment: That's correct. In case you want to access or update the content of the message. There are some APIs referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/insert-data-in-the-body

Comment: So can't I cast Outlook document to Word document like I can do in VSTO .net?

example:

`var inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
var item = (MailItem)inspector.CurrentItem;
var document = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;
var range = document.Application.Selection.Range;
var rng = (object)range;
var contentControl = document.ContentControls.Add(WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, ref rng);`

Comment: No, that isn't possible.